# How to manipulate a different element by css hover

Tags: css

I'd like to manipulate an elements' width by hovering and at the same time edit its neighbors elements width.

I thought I could do it like so:

```
.sw_2-technik:hover{
    width:60%;
}

.sw_2-technik:hover .sw_2.emotionen{
    width:40%;
}
```

Whereas the hovering of .sw_technik makes its width to 60% and .sw_2-emotionen to 40%. But that doesn't seem to work.

Do I really need to use JS for something like that?

---

Additional info:

the 2 containers are next to each others, like so

```
<div class="sw_2-technik"></div><div class="sw_2-emotionen"></div>
```

And I therefore also tried this code:

```
.sw_2-technik:hover + .emotionen{
    width:40%;
}
```

but that doesn't work neither.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to affect other elements when a div is hovered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered)

Comment: Could be indeed. Though after this explaination: 

.sw_2-technik:hover + .emotionen{
    width:40%;
}

would be the correct answer. But that doesn't work for me neither

Comment: Might just by mistake here, but with your classes shouldn't it be `.sw_2-technik:hover + .sw_2-emotionen{ width:40%; }`

Comment: My fault with wrong spelling. Thanks for guiding me to the right reference.

Comment: @Daiaiai Glad we can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ~ or +. Difference being is that + requires the element to be directly after the one being hovered, and ~ looks for the closest.

```
.sw_2-technik:hover ~ .sw_2.emotionen {
    color: blue;
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ka1yxv8z/

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is as already answered in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered) that one:

```
.sw_2-technik:hover{
    width:60%;
}

.sw_2-technik:hover + .sw_2-emotionen{
    width:40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In reply to your comment, this seems to work for me as indicated below.

```css
.sw_2-technik, .sw_2-emotionen {
  background: blue;
  padding: 2px;
}

.sw_2-technik + .sw_2-emotionen {
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sw_2-technik"></div>
<div class="sw_2-emotionen"></div>
```